# PVCS service getting down once the server CPU physical memory usage become high. Whats the issue and How to resolve it?

Tags: windows

Our PVCS service getting down once the physical memory usage of the server goes high. Once the server restarts(Not recommended) again the service will be up. Is there any permenant fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I resolved this issue by increasing the heapsize parameters...:-)

1.On the server system, open the following file in a text editor:

Windows as of VM 8.4.6: VM_Install\vm\common\bin\pvcsrunner.bat
Windows prior to VM 8.4.6: VM_Install\vm\common\bin\pvcsstart.bat
UNIX/Linux: VM_Install/vm/common/bin/pvcsstart.sh

2.Find the following line:

set JAVA_OPTS=

And set the value of the following parameters as needed:

-Xmsvaluem -Xmxvaluem

3.If you are running a VM release prior to 8.4.3, make sure -Dpvcs.mx= is followed by  the same value shown after -Xmx.

4.Save the file and restart the server.

The following is a rule of thumb when increasing the values for -Xmx: 

•256m -> 512m
•512m -> 1024m
•1024m -> 1280m
```

Answer (score 0):

As Riant points out above, adjusting the HEAP size is your best course of action here. I actually supported PVCS for nine years until this time in 2014 when I jumped ship.  Riant's numbers are exactly what I would recommend.

I would actually counsel a lot of customers to set -Xms and -Xmx to the same value (basically start it at 1024) because if your PDBs and/or your user community are large you're going to hit the ceiling quicker than you might realize.

Comment: I would have to work off of memory but here goes. Edit the pvcsstart.sh or pvcsstart.bat file and search for -Xms= or -Xmx=. The way the script is written there will be a different copy of that line for each OS if memory serves. Unfortunately I don't have a copy of the startup script on any of my machines any longer so I can't give you the fill exact syntax you would be looking for in the file. Sorry!